# Como lograr un fondo semi trasparente en una app para iOS hecha con Xcode? (Tipo iBooks )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app

mi pregunta es como se logra (Si es que se puede ) hacer que el fondo de la app que se esta creando en Xcode (Swift) sea semi transparente. algo parecido a iBooks en iOS que al abrirse no muestra un fondo blanco si no que muestra el fondo de pantalla del dispositivo iOS de manera difuminada.de tal manera que si el fondo de pantalla es verde la app se ve en color verde y por encima se muestran los libros o si es roja se muestra el fondo de color rojo etc etc.

-- anexo unas imágenes de iBooks en iOS para denotar lo que describo en la pregunta --

[image: Como se logra ese efecto de fondo difuminado ??[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDvcf.png)

Comment: Bienvenido.. por favor mira el [tour]

Comment: ¿Has buscado en el sitio? Creo que alguien hizo esta misma pregunta ayer o hace dos días. Voy a ver si la encuentro y te pongo el enlace.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes encontrar la respuesta aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953471/4809311

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Este código le aplica una ventana "semi transparente" a view. Por tanto, lo único que necesitas es tener una imagen o el fondo que deseas transparentar en view. Tienes distintos tipos de efectos transparentes en UIBlurEffectStyle. También puedes cambiar el alpha del transparentado en UIVisualEffectView aunque la documentación lo desaconseja.

Comment: Bien encontrado, explicado y gracias por la referencia. Mira [answer] por si se puede mejorar más la respuesta y [tour] para visitar el recorrido del sitio . Un saludo ^^